# Confusion on the meaning of the Vitali- Covering Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In Folland, Lemma 3.15 gives a version of the Vitali-Covering Lemma:

> **Lemma 3.15:** Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a collection of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and let $U= \bigcup_{B \in \mathscr{C}} B$. If
>   $c<m(U)$, there exists disjoint $B_{1}, \ldots, B_{k} \in \mathscr{C}$
>   such that $\sum_{j=1}^{k} m(B_{j})> 3^{-n} c$.

I am very unclear on the significance of this result.

Is it true that $U \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{k} 3 B_{j}$? If so, how is this implied by this lemma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Lemma is not quite easy to understand just by reading the terse proof.

However, the following picture from wiki is much helpful:

[image]

> 1. Green balls represent $B_j$
> 2. purple balls represent the balls $A_i$ with $A_i \cap Bj \neq \emptyset$

Anwser: **YES**

To explain it, notice the following:

1. No isolated purple balls.
2. Purple balls will no larger than the green balls if they intersect.
3. If two balls are of the same size and both are **almost disjoint**. Then choose one of them to be green ball $B$ and the other, purple $A$. Then $3B \supset A $ (Verify it just by drawing circle !)

So the result indeed imply that $U \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{k} 3 B_{j}$ (No purple balls are isolated from the covering.)

Also 1.~ 3. are implied by the proof of this Lemma. So the Lemma indeed implies this result and this picture.