# Folland's Version of Vitali's Covering Theorem Confusion

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, intuition

Here is Lemma 3.15 in Folland, which is a version the Vitali's Covering Lemma:

> **Lemma 3.15:** Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a collection of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and let $U= \bigcup_{B \in \mathscr{C}} B$. If
> $c<m(U)$, there exists disjoint $B_{1}, \ldots, B_{k} \in \mathscr{C}$
> such that $\sum_{j=1}^{k} m(B_{j})> 3^{-n} c$.

**I wonder if it is true that $U \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{k} 3 B_{j}$?**

An almost identical question were asked here : [Confusion on the meaning of the Vitali- Covering Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514894/confusion-on-the-meaning-of-the-vitali-covering-lemma). However, I am not very convinced of the answer given there. In particular, $\mathscr{C}$ is possibly an uncountable family of sets in the statement of Folland, whereas the picture given in the answer of the link, at best gives an intuition for the countable case.

In fact, my opinion is that $U$ may not be covered by the subcollection of $\{ 3B_i \}_i$ that we found. In particular, the use of the inner regularity of Lebesgue measure in the proof only gives a measure approximation, instead of an actual set containment relationship. We may probably recover set containment by attaching some sets with very small measure (maybe a null set?). However, I am not sure how to make this rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the linked thread is slightly incorrect in the sense that it is only true that $K \subset \displaystyle\bigcup_{j=1}^{k} B_j^*$, where $B_j^*$ is the ball with radius equal to $3$ times that of $B_j$ and centered at the same point as $B_j$ and $K$ is some compact set such that $K \subset U$ and $m(K)>c$.

It is trivial to come up with contrived counterexamples where we have $U \not\subset \displaystyle\bigcup_{j=1}^k B_j^*$. In particular, consider the case where $\mathscr{C}=\{B(x,1): x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$. Then since $m\left(\displaystyle\bigcup_{j=1}^k B_j^*\right)<\infty$, it can't possibly be the case that $U =\mathbb{R}^n \subset \displaystyle\bigcup_{j=1}^k B_j^*$ (Context aside, I think the better observation to make here is that this would imply $\mathbb{R}^n$ is totally bounded which it isn't).